# Return top customer by total value, millions of docs across two collections via lookup aggregated. Performance problems

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions, database-performance, query-performance

I have two collections: orders_A and orders_B (web and app orders) with the same structure:

orders_A:

```
{"_id": 100001,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 10,
"record_id": 11111,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "12/07/2018"},

{"_id": 100002,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 15,
"record_id": 11112,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "13/07/2018"}
```

orders_B:

```
{"_id": 102201,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 5,
"record_id": 22222,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "09/07/2018"},

{"_id": 102202,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 5,
"record_id": 22223,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "10/07/2018"}
```

I have this query that i'm using to get the total payments for a single customer:

```
db.orders_A.aggregate([

{$match: {customer_id: 346085}},

{$project: 
{customer_id:1, 
Record_ID:1, 
order_value:1}},

{$group:
    {_id: “$customer_id”,
    value_of_orders_a: {
        $sum: “$order_value”}}},

{$lookup:
    {from: “orders_B”,
    localField: “_id”,
    foreignField: “customer_id”,
    as: “orders_B”}},

{$project:
    {total_value: 
{$add: [“$value_of_orders_a”, 
{$sum: “$orders_B.order_value”}]
}}}
] )
```

Output: { “_id”: 346035, total_value”: 15980.85 }

This can be done in about 200 ms - good enough for me

The problem comes in when I want to answer a question like "Which customer_id has the highest total order value?"

Orders_A and Orders_B can be millions of documents long

Running a query to just get 5 customer's total orders takes 2 minutes when i'm not using $match on customer ID

I have created indexes on customer_id in both Orders_A and Orders_B

Basically I want help running this:

db.orders_A.aggregate([

```
{$project: 
{customer_id:1, 
Record_ID:1, 
order_value:1}},

{$group:
    {_id: “$customer_id”,
    value_of_orders_a: {
        $sum: “$order_value”}}},

{$lookup:
    {from: “orders_B”,
    localField: “_id”,
    foreignField: “customer_id”,
    as: “orders_B”}},

{$project:
{
_id : 1,
total_value: 
    {$add: [“$value_of_orders_a”, 
    {$sum: “$orders_B.order_value”}]
}}},

{$sort: {total_value: 1}},

{$limit : 1}
] )
```

How can I run this query?

Desired output:

{ “_id”: 346036, total_value”: 1200000.00}

Version of MongoDB: 4.0.1

Thanks a lot

Comment: There are 600,000 distinct customers for orders_A, and 7,000 for orders_B

Comment: To start, you should take out the `$project` stage.  The query engine will do this for you. Next, could you show us the `$explain` output?

Comment: Remove the project stage? Would you mind explaining why? This is how I'm summing up my collections. I need to sum the customer's orders from a and b. Sorry I'm new to mongodb, I'm from a SQL background

Comment: It took 20 minutes for my query that returns the top 5. Output: 2018-08-26T15:54:31.302+0000 I COMMAND  [conn9] command payments.orders_A appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: aggregate { aggregate: "ordersA", pipeline: [ { $match: { customer_id: { $ne: "" } } }, { $group: { _id: "$customer_id", total_value: { $sum: "$Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars" } } }, { $sort: { total_value: -1.0 } }, { $limit: 5.0 } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("42fc2827-bfd0-4053-9567-e7ef349e804e") }, $db: "payments" }

Comment: planSummary: IXSCAN { customer_id: 1 } keysExamined:10890499 docsExamined:10890498 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:111553 nreturned:5 reslen:299 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 112427 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 112427 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 112427 } } } protocol:op_msg 1181015ms